# Partial index of JSONB field with type cast in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

There is a table, which has `metadata` jsonb field.
I created a partial index `where (metadata->>'processed')::boolean is FALSE`.

I can not clarify, will it work only when `{'processed': 'false'}`, or also for case where is no `processed` key. Will this index also work for record with no key as `{}` for example?

Answer (score 1):

This index will only cover rows that have a key called "processed" of which the value is "false", 0 or any other literal that can be cast to `boolean`.

I consider such an index problematic because if someone tries to insert a "metadata" field where "processed" equals "sheep", for instance, then the insert operation will fail because the expression "sheep" cannot be evaluated as `boolean`.

I think that indexes are not supposed to act as check constraints because it can cause a lot of confusion.